# How to build Chilitags with CMake on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

Chilitags are a C++ cross-platform software library for the detection and identification of 2D fiducial markers. The whole project is here: 
https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags

When I try to build Chilitags, I have done these things on my macOS:

```
$ cd ~
$ gitclone https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags.git
$ cd chilitags
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

Then the error occurs to be:

```
CMake Error: The source "/Users/Icarus/chilitags/CMakeLists.txt" does not
match the source "/Users/Icarus/chilitags/src/CMakeLists.txt" used to 
generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

I don't know how to handle this since the readme.md file told me to do so. I don't know how to modify the two CMakeLists.

Comment: Do you get this on the first run? From the error it looks like you first ran `cmake ../src` then tried to run `cmake ..`.

Comment: Ah, I found that the previous cmake .. produces cmakecache file and it fixs when I delete it. Thanks